# How to extract patients ventilated for 48hrs or more who received disease "Yes" in R?

Tags: r

```
df=data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
              date_of_admission=c("2020-05-18","2020-05-18","2020-05-18","2020-05-18"
                                  ,"2020-04-28","2020-04-28","2020-04-28",
                                  "2020-05-03","2020-05-03","2020-05-03","2020-05-03"),
              dates=c("2020-05-19","2020-05-20","2020-05-21","2020-05-22",
                      "2020-05-07","2020-05-08","2020-05-09",
                      "2020-05-08","2020-05-09","2020-05-10","2020-05-11"),
              disease=c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No")
              )
df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ti2r.jpg)

Please assume my data is related to ventilated patients. I want to extract number of ventilated patients for 48hrs or more (2 days or more). Admission date is constant for each patients. Dates are related to 5th month but admission date may be out of 05th month. Another thing is those patients were ventilated at admission date as well. Therefore, when we extract, we need to think about admission date as well. Finally I want percentage of ventilated patients who received disease "Yes".

Comment: Can you share specific questions about code? What have you tried?

Comment: What goes in the column `dates`? If admission date is constant, why are there differences in the `date_of_admission` column? How can we see which patients are ventilated at admission date?

Comment: What is your expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate) # for the date function

# read in as a data.table
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
              date_of_admission=c("2020-05-18","2020-05-18","2020-05-18","2020-05-18"
                                  ,"2020-04-28","2020-04-28","2020-04-28",
                                  "2020-05-03","2020-05-03","2020-05-03","2020-05-03"),
              dates=c("2020-05-19","2020-05-20","2020-05-21","2020-05-22",
                      "2020-05-07","2020-05-08","2020-05-09",
                      "2020-05-08","2020-05-09","2020-05-10","2020-05-11"),
              disease=c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No")
)

# number of patients in the data set 2 days or longer (difference is > 0):
nrow(dt[, .(stay = max(date(dates) - date(date_of_admission))), by = id][stay > 0L])
[1] 3

# proportion of patients with disease == "Yes
uniqueN(dt[disease == "Yes", c("id", "disease")])/uniqueN(dt[, id])
[1] 0.6666667
```